# GestureDetector in Stack blocked by foreground widget. HitTestBehavior.translucent not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I am trying to create a multi layered screen using a stack which allows the user to interact with both the foreground and background widgets.

I have started a basic outline for the screen however even when using `HitTestBehavior.translucent` the console only prints `red pressed` when pressing the translucent red container. I would like for console to print both strings when red/purple container is pressed.

Below is the code I used.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final children = <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          debugPrint('blue pressed');
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ];

    if (exercise.instructions.isNotEmpty) {
      children.add(
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint('red pressed');
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 400,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red.withAlpha(100),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: children,
    );
  }
```

Below is the screen produced:

[image: Screen produced by code]